# Confusing with the concept of normalizer $N_G(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

I'm Confusing with the concept of normalizer $N_G(H)$.

It's a stupid question, sorry I'm new in this subject.

Following the Hungerford's concept:

> If $H$ acts by conjugation on the set $S$ of all subgroups of $G$,
>   then the subgroup of $H$ fixing $K\in S$, namely $\{h\in H\mid hKh^{-1}\}$
>   is called the normalizer of $K$.

Following the wikipedia's concept (regular concept)

> The normalizer of S in the group G is defined to be
>
> $N_G(S)=\{g\in G\mid gS=Sg \} $

I'm a little confused, why in the Hungerford's concept, $H$ has to act by conjugation on the set $S$? these concepts are the equivalents?

I need help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $gS=Sg\Leftrightarrow gSg^{-1}=S$.

Comment: (In Hungerford's definition you need $\{h\in H \mid hKh^{-1}=K\}$. That $=K$ is important...)

Comment: @user1729 I know this, my question is why $H$ has to act by conjugation on the set S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, saying $gS=Sg$ is the same as $gSg^{-1}=S$, so the definitions are equivalent.

The first definition simply emphasizes the fact that normalizers are just a special kind of [stabilizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Fixed_points_and_stabilizer_subgroups). The group $H$ in Hungerford's definition doesn't *have* to act by conjugation as a prerequisite. Rather, we willingly *make* it act by conjugation, and see what kind of stabilizers we will get.

Comment: yes, you have pointed out exactly in my doubt when you wrote the second paragraph. thank you a lot, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in Hungerford's definition you need $\{h\in H \mid hKh^{-1}=K\}$. That $=K$ is important...

Then, $$\begin{align*}N_H(K)&=\{h\in H \mid hKh^{-1}=K\}\\&=\{h\in H \mid hK=Kh\}\end{align*}$$ which coincides with the Wikipedia definition.

The point is that $gKg^{-1}=K\Leftrightarrow gK=Kg$. I will leave the proof of this fact to you.

Comment: I know this, my question is why H has to act by conjugation on the set S. Thanks for you answer

Comment: I do not understand your question then. Are you asking "How is conjugation an action"? Or "Why in the definition of normaliser do we talk about conjugation?". An action has a stabiliser, and in conjugation the stabiliser is the normaliser.

Comment: yes, sorry, I understand now, thank you again